# How to assign a string to a TextBlock?

Tags: c#, textblock, windows-rt

Does anyone know how to assign a string to a textblock?

e.x. I have a string, with variable content, and a textBlock. The text of the textBlock should always match the content of the string.

```
string number;

public MainPage()
{
    //the textBlock text should now be "1"
    number = "1";

    //the textBlock text should now be "second"
    number = "second";
}
```

I tryed to do this automatically with bindings, but I couldn't find a solution.

regards,
Cristian

Comment: Why not use [`TextBlock.Text`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.text(v=vs.110).aspx) property

Comment: I use this already, but it's very cumbersome to write this under each change of the string.

Comment: Define a private property for your string and it is setter, set the value to your `TextBlock.Text` that is what you can do to mimic it.

Comment: Ok, then I have to do this with TextBlock.Text

Comment: Look at data binding.

Comment: @Habib Data binding is a much cleaner way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Databinding to work you need to have a a Property and not just a simple member variable. And your Datacontext class has to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged Interface.

```
public class MyDataContext : INotifyPropertyChanged

    private string number;
    public string Number {
        get {return number;}
        set {number = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Number");}
    }

// implement the interface of INotifyPropertyChanged here
// ....
}


public class MainWindow() : Window
{
     private MyDataContext ctx = new MyDataContext();

     //This thing is out of my head, so please don't nail me on the details
     //but you should get the idea ...
     private void InitializeComponent() {
        //...
        //... some other initialization stuff
        //...

        this.Datacontext = ctx;
     }

}
```

And you may use this in the XAML as following

```
<Window ...>
    <!-- some other controls etc. -->
    <TextBlock Text={Binding Number} />
    <!-- ... -->
</Window>
```

Comment: Note that for this to work, you need to assign to "Number" not "number". Showing the binding string setup would also make this a much better answer. +1 for the correct approach though.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I edited my answer according to your suggestion. It's not the prettiest solution, but one should get the idea.